# Metrics or operations on genome sequences in human genomic research?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequencing

Edit distance may be an important metric for measuring the similarity of two genome sequences.  For example, if *A* = GCAATT and *B*= CGAATA, then the edit distance of *A* and *B* is 3. Such a metric is intuitive and may be useful in comparing the similarity of two sequences.

I wonder is there any more complex or advanced metrics used in human genomic research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of how similar two DNA or protein sequences are, is one of the most important problems in bioinformatics. While there is no definitive answer Bayseian statistics are often used to group sequences. There is a good explanation of the theory on this wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference_in_phylogeny).

Alternatively one of the most commonly used programs to find similar sequences is BLAST. It is getting a little bit dated but you can find an overview on the statistics used by this program on this [page](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/tutorial/)

But there are many other methods out there.